# How to run Jupyter Notebook on GPU for Julia?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, gpu, jupyter

I'm working with quite a large dataset to plot some graphs with Julia on Jupyter notebook on my laptop. But while plotting it's taking too much time to load and my laptop starts lagging. So, I thought if I run the code on GPU it might lessen the lagging. But I couldn't find any clear instructions on the net about set up Jupyter Notebook on GPU for running Julia.
I'm working on Windows 10 and I have a dedicated GPU on my laptop with the following specifications:

```
***NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
Driver version: 27.21.14.5241
Driver date:    9/23/2020
DirectX version:    12 (FL 11.0)
Physical location:  PCI bus 1, device 0, function 0
Utilization 0%
Dedicated GPU memory    0.0/4.0 GB
Shared GPU memory   0.0/3.9 GB
GPU Memory  0.0/7.9 GB***
```

Can anyone please help me to run Jupyter Notebook with GPU for Julia?

Comment: Note that the _first_ time you try to plot in a Julia script/notebook, it is "normal" it takes a while (but subsequent plotting commands should be fast).You are not going to mitigate this lagging by using the GPU. First-time to plot lag has been improved in Julia 1.5 and even more in the upcoming 1.6 release...

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues here:

- rendering the plot with GPU
- showing the plot in the web browser.

Regarding the first issue there is `GLMakie.jl` that is using OpenGL (and hence can use GPU) for image rendering.
Another option is to use Julia's GPU libraries such as `CuArrays` and render the plot yourself using Array operations on GPU. There are many tutorial how to do it - they mostly use JuliaSet for illustration - e.g. https://nextjournal.com/sdanisch/julia-gpu-programming

The second issue is actually showing the plot in Jupyter notebook. Jupyter itself is a headless process and the actual visualization is happening in the web browser. Nvidia has "GPU affinity" setting that allows you to select which hardware is using by a particular application when plotting on screen. You can find the appropriate setting in NVidia Control Panel. See the picture below. However, for most cases I do not expect it to increase your performance because most of the job is an actual image rendering.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you share some resources on setting up Nvidia for Chrome as I'm trying to do it on Nvidia Control Panel, it says 

`Access Denied

Failed to apply selected setting to your system`

Comment: Administrative rights? I extended the answer. Nevertheless perhaps only point 1 is important in my answer. I have no idea why someone would use this setting for the web browser.